# Create spfile from pfile

Tags: oracle

I'm having a problem in creating spfile from pfile.I think I don't have permission to write on Oracle Home. I'm using Windows 8

```
SQL> startup nomount pfile='initlittle2.ora.txt';
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  644468736 bytes
Fixed Size                  1376520 bytes
Variable Size             192941816 bytes
Database Buffers          444596224 bytes
Redo Buffers                5554176 bytes
SQL> create spfile from pfile;
create spfile from pfile
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file
'A:\ORACLEBASE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\OLTP2\DATABASE\INITLITTLE2.ORA'
```

Any workaround for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you created your pfile with a double extension `.ora.txt` (Windows Notepad sometimes does this).

You can try to:

- rename the pfile removing the `.txt` extension, or
- specify the full path to your parameter file in the `CREATE` statement, e.g. `CREATE SPFILE FROM PFILE = 'c:\yourpath\initlittle2.ora.txt';`